# Twitter @anywhere login having issues

Tags: twitter, authentication, oauth, twitter-anywhere

I'm using the new twitter @anywhere api for logging in on the client using a popup. The api docs are here
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/anywhere/welcome#auth-events

Ive created a very simple example of their api, but after hitting "connect" on the popup, twitter just says "Something is technically wrong" as seen here in this screenshot
http://cl.ly/0A321R1Z2W1o3v0P0t0z

Here is my setup for doing this (note ive already created my app on twitter)

```javascript
var api = "http://platform.twitter.com/anywhere.js?id={MY_API_KEY}&v=1";
$.getScript(api,function() {

            twttr.anywhere(function (tw) {

                console.log("tw",tw);

                // bind auth compelte event
                tw.bind("authComplete", function (e, user) {
                    console.log("tw auth complete",e,user);
                });

                // calling sign in triggeers the above event
                tw.signIn();

            }); 

        });
```

So it opens the popup, lets me sign into twitter, and then when I hit connect, i get that odd error from twitter.

Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Thanks!

Update - I found this page of people having similar problems, but the solution they offered didn't change anything.

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1286

And it might be important to note the domain I'm using is http://changeup.dev  its a local domain. I have it setup in my hosts file already.

Comment: SO, i Figured it out. You NEED to have a callback URL for your app, (on the developer page) even though it says you don't. The callback URL needs to match your authorized domain as well.

Then, in your app, the URL that the callback is calling, NEEDS to include the twitter api. THEN, and only THEN will the window automatically close and execute the authComplete callback.

I did this on the same page I was logging in from

if(location.hash && location.hash.indexOf("oauth_access_token") != -1) {
    $.getScript("http://platform.twitter.com/anywhere.js?id={API_KEY}");
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SO, i Figured it out.  You NEED to have a callback URL for your app, (on the developer page) even though it says you don't. The callback URL needs to match your authorized domain as well.

Then, in your app, the URL that the callback is calling, NEEDS to include the twitter api. THEN, and only THEN will the window automatically close and execute the authComplete callback.

I did this on the same page I was logging in from

```
if(location.hash && location.hash.indexOf("oauth_access_token") != -1) {
```